# Make a button create a new item when clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Hey I am trying to create a notes app in windows form and I cant figure out how to create a new item with a button (usually done by right clicking on the app name > add new > windows form)

for example;

if button1 is clicked create a new form called note1

thanks

Comment: is there a Form 'Note' already defined in your app, creating a new form totally from scratch is complex and not usually needed

Comment: no there isnt, what I want to happen is if a button is pressed a form will be created and opened but it needs to have set data already so it has a text box on it

Comment: A) Create a form, b) Add textbox and anything else needed. c) add code to event handler to create `new` form and show it d) Profit!  All the stepos are there in your post and comment

Comment: how do I do that? I have been trying for hours and cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a second Form in the designer, call it Note.

add all the controls you want.

Now in the Main form when you want to show the Note form do (in a click handler say)

```
  var note1 = new Note();
  note.Show();
```

Comment: can this create new items as many times as the button is pressed or just once?

Comment: @OfficerDonut why dont you try it and see :-)